# How to find specific string within data-type using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorting through a portfolio dynamically at http://shoeshinedesign.com/css/portfolio/

The first listed project has two categories: "todd-ao" and "soundelux." The filter buttons up top sort the projects by through jQuery, connecting the `li` class of the filter button and the `data-type` of the specific projects.

Since the filter buttons are marked by one class, whenever I have two categories in the `data-type` parameter the jQuery script isn't recognizing each specific word in the `data-type`.

I need a was to modify my jQuery to allow for multiple words in the `data-type` and the buttons to still sort accordingly.

**Here's my HTML mark up:**

```
<!-- FILTER BUTTONS -->
<ul class="portfoliofilter">
  <li class="all">
    <a href="#">All</a>
  </li>
  <li class="todd-ao">
    <a href="#">Todd-AO</a>
  </li>
  <li class="soundelux">
    <a href="#">Soundelux</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- PROJECT LISTING -->

<ul id="portfoliolist3column"> 
  <li class="portfolio" data-type="todd-ao soundelux">
    <!-- 
        THIS PROJECT WON'T SORT DUE TO DATA-TYPE
        NOT SPECIFICALLY MATCHING FILTER LI CLASS
    -->
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio" data-type="todd-ao">
    <!-- SORTS -->
  </li>
  <li class="portfolio" data-type="soundelux">
    <!-- SORTS -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery markup:** (focus on `else` of conditional)

```
jQuery('.portfoliofilter li').click(function(e) {
  jQuery(".portfoliofilter li a").addClass("portfoliobutton_noselect");
  jQuery(".portfoliofilter li a").removeClass("portfoliobutton");   
  jQuery(this).children('a').removeClass("portfoliobutton_noselect");
  jQuery(this).children('a').addClass("portfoliobutton");

  var filterClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');

  if (filterClass == 'all') {
    var $filteredData = $data.find('.portfolio');
  } else {
    var $filteredData = $data.find('.portfolio[data-type=' + filterClass + ']');
  }

  jQuery($list).quicksand($filteredData, {
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'swing',
    adjustHeight: 'dynamic',
    enhancement: function() { }
  }, function() {
    addPrettyPhoto();
  });

  return false;
});
```

Is there a way to have the `$data.find` simply look for a string and not an exact match with the `filterClass`?

**EDIT**
Here's the final, in-context code, as provided by @pimvdb below.

```
jQuery('.portfoliofilter li').click(function(e) {

            jQuery(".portfoliofilter li a").addClass("portfoliobutton_noselect");
            jQuery(".portfoliofilter li a").removeClass("portfoliobutton"); 
            jQuery(this).children('a').removeClass("portfoliobutton_noselect");
            jQuery(this).children('a').addClass("portfoliobutton");

            var filterClass = jQuery(this).attr('class');

            if (filterClass == 'all') {
                var $filteredData = $data.find('.portfolio');
            } else {
                var $filteredData = $data.find(".portfolio").filter(function() {
                    return ~jQuery(this).data("type").split(" ").indexOf(filterClass);
                  });
            }

            jQuery($list).quicksand($filteredData, {
                duration: 500,
                easing: 'swing',
                adjustHeight: 'dynamic',
                enhancement: function() {

                }
            }, function(){
                addPrettyPhoto();
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: You have a `.portfolio[data-type=` selector, but in your HTML there are no such elements (which both have that class and a `data-type` attribute). Is that correct?

Comment: You're right. I accidentally deleted it when posting here. I added it back. It is on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a function to `.find` and split the `data-` items: http://jsfiddle.net/mXbGJ/. This is an example of the idea, not an exact implementation for your case, but it's easy to glue it into your code I guess:

```
$("...").find(function() {
    return ~$(this).data("items").split(" ").indexOf("b");
}).css("background-color", "red");
```

---

**Edit:** this logs the correct ones I think:

```
jQuery('.portfoliofilter li').click(function() {
  var x = jQuery(this).attr("class");
  console.log($("#portfoliolist3column").find(".portfolio").filter(function() {
    return ~jQuery(this).data("type").split(" ").indexOf(x);
  }));
});
```

Comment: I've been messing with this and at one point it worked on jsfiddle, but the same code would not work on the site. (I checked cache, etc. too). Any specific breakdown of this you could offer would be hugely helpful.

Comment: For example, this works in jsfiddle: 
`if (filterClass == 'all') {
                    var $filteredData = $data.find('.portfolio');
                } else {
                    var $filteredData = $("li.portfolio").filter(function() {
    return ~$(this).data("type").split(" ").indexOf('' + filterClass + '');
});                
                }`

BUT not on the live site.

Comment: @Stephen C.: Perhaps you need to use `$data.find` there as well. You're trying to filter those elements, aren't you?

Comment: As is being revealed, I'm not very knowledgeable in js. Here's what I have now. I tried variations with no luck. `else {
     var $filteredData = $data.find(function() { 
      return ~$('.portfolio').data("type").split(" ").indexOf('' + filterClass + '');
     });
    }`

Comment: @Stephen C.: This one seems to log the correct ones. See my edit.